# Manipulating a version number w/o regex?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a 4-digit version-number ("1234") and would like to insert "_" to separate the digits ("1_2_3_4").
The only idea I came up with was using regex:

```
<?
  $str="1234";
  $s1 = preg_replace("/\d/","$0_",$str,3);
  echo "$str|$s1";
?>
```

But I have a nagging feeling there must be a more elegant way to achive this w/o rx, by using just the string-manipulation methods. Any suggestions?

Comment: `str_split()` + `join()`?

Answer (score 2):

Using your example string, you could also use `str_split` and `implode` in this case:

```
$str = '1234';
$newstr = implode('_', str_split($str));
echo $newstr; // 1_2_3_4
```

Comment: Thanks, that's cool. I must admit had forgotten str_split <blush>  ;-)

Comment: @MBaas yeah these string functions should suffice